# Last touched directory bash script

Tags: bash, directory

I need a bash script which finds the last touched directory from a path and gives its name back as a value i can use for further commands.

For EXAMPLE I have a diretory like:

0  0.0002  0.0004  0.0006  0.0008  0.001  0.0012  0.0014  0.001454

And I need a script which gives 0.001454 (last touched).

Comment: "Last touched" would typically mean "with the newest mtime". Do you intend that to mean something different here (such as "with a name corresponding with the largest floating-point value")? Note also, that if you want "touched" to include non-modifying *access*, then this would only work if your filesystem has atimes enabled (which are often turned off for performance reasons).

Comment: ...please clarify exactly what you mean. (If you want to demonstrate that logic is finding the latest mtime, by the way, consider using `ls -l` or a `stat` command that shows mtimes in your example; otherwise, showing a list of filenames without the metadata that's supposed to be used to make this decision offers no value at all).

Comment: @ charles:
Basically it's not important for my case because the last touched directory is the one with the highest floating point number (they are created successive with increasing numbers). But I guess choosing based on the floating point number would be saver if the directory is touched later on by another program.

Comment: It was a little unclear from my first post, I guess, so my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `stat` from coreutils:

```
stat -c "%Z %n" -- * | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-
```